# can someone please explain me the meaning of "It's not cut" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, american-english, slang

I've playing a game called gta san andreas and there's a phrase that i'm no understanding at all the context is:

the character called CJ and the other called big smoke have to go to cj's mom funeral and big smoke have a car and cj praise big smoke's car and big smoke says this phrase

> You know me. it's not cut. keep the value in it. keep it real

I'll post a link to a 10 seconds video in case you want to see

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vu3jNyhmodU

**OBS: I'm not a native english speaker**

Comment: Already discussed here - https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/its-not-cut.3686555/. Messed with, harmed by overpersonalizing it.

Comment: I suspect that it's a reference to street drugs being 'cut' or diluted with the addition of other substances such as sugar and chalk. This  increases the number of hits that can be sold from the consignment and, in some cases makes the drug "safer" because the potency is reduced.

Comment: Given the style of car, I suspect his praise is sarcastic. It seems fairly pedestrian, rather than some sort of luxury car.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Lol, it doesn't appearing to me in the search, i'll give it a look

Comment: @BoldBen yes a user on reddit said the same thing, i ask here because his answer seems confuse to me, maybe i need to improve my anglish more

Comment: @alphabet yeah, that's what I though too, and then maybe big smoke answer to Play Cj's game

Comment: @BoldBen I believe that in some circles "cut" is a euphemism for circumcised, in other words modified. The car is unmodified, that is "stock".